# Three Part Table - Table Note on the Top

Tags: positioning, threeparttable, tablenotes

I am using the `threeparttable` environment to create tables in my document. I want that `tablenotes` should appear right after the caption of the table and before the actual table; instead, it appears on the bottom of the table. How I can do this?

A minimal working example is given below:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, twoside]{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage[para]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{array,booktabs,longtable,tabularx}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}% <-- added
\usepackage{caption}% <-- added
\setlength{\LTcapwidth}{7in}
\usepackage{ltablex}% <-- added
\usepackage{siunitx}% <-- added
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttablex}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
        \begin{threeparttable}[b]
        \footnotesize
        \centering
        \caption{Multinomial Model}
            \begin{tabular}{lrr}
    \toprule
    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{ABS} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{CB} \\
    \midrule
    (Intercept) & 5.482 & 3.4871 \\
    ABC & 1.1173 & 1.1933 \\
    DEF & 8.1752* & 2.6836 \\
    \bottomrule
            \multicolumn{3}{c}{*p<0.1; **p<0.05; ***p<0.01} \\
            \bottomrule
            \end{tabular}%
            \label{tab:mlogit}%
            \begin{tablenotes}
    \footnotesize
    Note: These are estimates of multinomial logit model. 
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}%
\end{document}
```

Comment: Have you tried inserting the `tablenotes` environment *before* the *tabular* environment?

Comment: yes but in this case table note is moved before the caption and I want it between Table caption and the actual table.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to move "Note" to the table caption:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, twoside]{article}
\usepackage[para]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{booktabs,longtable,tabularx}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage{caption}
\setlength{\LTcapwidth}{7in}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttablex}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
        \begin{threeparttable}[b]
        \footnotesize
        \centering
\caption[Multinomial Model]% <-- appear in LoT if exist
        {Multinomial Model\vspace{1ex}
        \footnotesize
        Note: These are estimates of multinomial logit model.
                            }
        \begin{tabular}{lrr}
    \toprule
& \multicolumn{1}{c}{ABS} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{CB} \\
    \midrule
(Intercept) & 5.482 & 3.4871 \\
ABC & 1.1173 & 1.1933 \\
DEF & 8.1752* & 2.6836 \\
    \midrule[1pt]
\multicolumn{3}{c}{*p<0.1; **p<0.05; ***p<0.01} \\
    \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}%
        \label{tab:mlogit}%
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}%
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: For a simple note like this that works well (+1).  I'm not so sure it would work for the sort of tablenotes I've used, which are along the lines of `a) from Ref. 1\\b) from Ref.2 (Ref. 3 gives the range 1-2)... ` But in my case putting it on top of the table would be strange.

Comment: I tried but it did not work. Following error appears. `File ended while scanning use of \caption@ydblarg`

Comment: @AhmedArif, it works with your MWE. If your final document has different document class and preambe, than you should inform us about them.

Comment: @ChrisH, in my answer the `tablenotes`are not used. If OP would instead `\multicolumn{3}{c}{*p<0.1; **p<0.05; ***p<0.01}` use `tablenotes` correctly, than the notes`*p<0.1`, `**p<0.05` and ` ***p<0.0` is possible to manage to be referable. Please ask separate question, if you have problem with this issues.

Comment: @Zarko mine worked fine a couple of years ago.  I was just pointing out that your answer was a substitute table note for `tablenotes` in the OP's case but not in all cases.  The refs were just an example of such a case.

Answer (score 0):

I would just add it to the table itself:

```
....
\begin{tabular}{lrr}
\multicolumn{3}{p{6cm}}{Note: These are estimated of multinomial logit model.}\\
\toprule
...
```

Comment: But in case table note is a bit longer, it creates problems.

Answer (score 0):

You could define a `swapthreeparttable` environment as follows, but probably you should simply add the note to the caption.

Note that you still need to enter the text of the notes after the table.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, twoside]{article}
\usepackage[para]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newbox\globalTPTbox
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{swapthreeparttable}
 {\patchcmd{\TPT@measurement}
    {\par\box\@tempboxb}
    {\global\setbox\globalTPTbox=\copy\@tempboxb}
    {}{}%
  \threeparttable}
 {\par\medskip\box\globalTPTbox\endthreeparttable}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
\centering

\begin{swapthreeparttable}
\caption{Multinomial Model}
\label{tab:mlogit}

\begin{tabular}{lrr}
  \toprule
  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{ABS} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{CB} \\
  \midrule
  (Intercept) & 5.482          & 3.4871 \\
  ABC         & 1.1173         & 1.1933 \\
  DEF         & 8.1752\rlap{*} & 2.6836 \\
  \midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
  \multicolumn{3}{c}{\footnotesize *$\,p<0.1$; **$\,p<0.05$; ***$\,p<0.01$} \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\begin{tablenotes}
\footnotesize
Note: These are estimates of multinomial logit model. 
\end{tablenotes}

\end{swapthreeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Here's the version I'd prefer (actually I wouldn't use `threeparttable` at all).

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, twoside]{article}
\usepackage[para]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h!]
\centering

\begin{threeparttable}
\caption[Multinomial Model]{Multinomial Model. Note: These are estimates of multinomial logit model.}
\label{tab:mlogit}

\begin{tabular}{lrr}
  \toprule
  & \multicolumn{1}{c}{ABS} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{CB} \\
  \midrule
  (Intercept) & 5.482          & 3.4871 \\
  ABC         & 1.1173         & 1.1933 \\
  DEF         & 8.1752\rlap{*} & 2.6836 \\
  \midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
  \multicolumn{3}{c}{\footnotesize *$\,p<0.1$; **$\,p<0.05$; ***$\,p<0.01$} \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]